How to connect a tableau dashboard to a dataset?
I have received a task as follows:
Share a Tableau Workbook and demonstrate how to do the following in Tableau. If you do not have your own Workbook, this can be sample data.

Connect a dashboard to a dataset
Create a dashboard parameter and calculated field
Publish a report**

For the given tasks I am confused as how to go forward. I am aware on how to connect a dataset to a new worksheet but in this scenario how do we connect a dataset to an already built dashboard.
Additionally is dashboard Parameter any different from a regular parameter in tableau?

You need to better define the request: point 1-2-3 are quite straightforward; why do you add "onnect a dataset to an already built dashboard"?
When you refer to dshboard, you mean it or you're referring to the whole workbook?
That being said, creating a parameter is quite simple an probably the request is to create a "simple parameter" which will be used within a dashboard having a dynamic calculated field referring to it.
